# Google Sheets ODBC driver

Tags: google-sheets, odbc

I want to develop a **Google Sheets ODBC driver** like **CData ODBC driver** in `C# windows application`.

CData OBDC driver access my Gmail account provide following connection details:

```
DRIVER= {CData ODBC Driver for GoogleSheets};
_persist_oauthaccesstoken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; 
_persist_oauthexpiresin=3600;
_persist_oauthrefreshtoken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
_persist_token_timestamp=1503999951866
```

Here I want to generate **`oauthaccesstoken, oauthexpiresin, oauthrefreshtoken, token_timestamp.`**

I have **`Client ID and Client secret`**. How to generate above keys?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using following connection string to connect google sheet.

```
DRIVER={CData ODBC Driver for GoogleSheets};Other='InitiateOAuth=GETANDREFRESH;CheckPromptMode=false;OAuth SettingsLocation=C:\Users\Test\New Text Document.txt';
```

Here **'OAuth SettingsLocation'** is a text file that contain access token of our gmail account.

I hope It's useful.It's work for me.